# get number of unique custId for each contract

Tags: python

I have below data.csv

```
custId,contract,zone,teamcode,projectcode,time
2,2345,us_east,Red,A,5s
1,2345,us_west,Blue,B,1s
2,2346,eu_west,Yellow,C,2s
1,2345,us_west,Blue,D,1s
3,2346,eu_west,Yellow,E,2s
```

I don't want to use pandas here.

I am new to python and I have no idea how to figure this out. I managed to read the data using csv but I don't know how to proceed next.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Edit: I need to find number of unique custId for each contract.

Comment: Please clarify your problem as it's unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: you can try to add them to a set when reading the row.

Comment: I guess in each contract there are a lot of customers and you want to know how many customers are in each contract is that right ?

Comment: yes @AmineMessaoudi

Comment: @JustCurious Please check my answer.

Comment: @JustCurious Please provide your expected answer as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need `collections.defaultdict` with `set`.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
unique_C = defaultdict(set)
with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)   #Skip header
    for row in reader:
        unique_C[row[1]].add(row[0])
print(unique_C)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'2345': set(['1', '2']), '2346': set(['3', '2'])})
```

Comment: +1 as it solves it in a quite understandable way. One question I got, why a `defaultdict` of `set` and not `list`

Comment: OP needs Unique custId  for each contact. That is why I have used a `set `object here.

Comment: @Rakesh, I am new to python. Can you elaborate more please. I did not understand the `unique_C[row[1]].add(row[0])`

Comment: `unique_C` is a `dict` with key as `contract` and value as `set` of `custId`

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want to count how many customers are involved in each contract.

If that is the case then here is how you can achieve it, without using Pandas

```
import csv

file = open('data.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)

# We create a list of all unique contracts
contracts = set([row[1] for row in reader])

# We create an array that will contain how many customers in each contract
array = []

# For each contract
for contract in contracts:

    # We initialize the number of customers
    count = 0

    # We loop through the lines
    for row in reader:

        row_contract = row[1]

        # If we find a line containing the contract
        if row_contract  == contract:

            # We increment the number of customers for the current contract
            count += 1

    array.append([contract, count])
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[[2345, 3], [2346, 2]]
```